# How does Paranoid work for obfuscating strings in android

Tags: android, obfuscation

I have read the documentation of `Paranoid` dependency used to obfuscate strings in android https://github.com/MichaelRocks/paranoid but I am not getting where are the original strings stored and is there any method to retrieve them back???

I tried googling and found no answers for this question

Comment: For any random library you find on github, do check the [issues](https://github.com/MichaelRocks/paranoid/issues/70) to see what level of support (if any) exists.